# ACF repeater fields (on and options page) within a Wordpress MU not returning data

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, multisite

I seem to have a problem retrieving ACF repeater fields (on and options page) within a Wordpress Multisite environment.

(the options pages are on the child sites)

This is my code below:

```
$bids = Array();
$blogs = wp_get_sites();

foreach ($blogs as $blog) {
    array_push($bids, $blog['blog_id']);
}

$original_blog_id = get_current_blog_id();

$k = 0;
foreach($bids as $bid) {
    switch_to_blog($bid);

    // this works
    $centre_facebook_link = get_field('centre_facebook_link','option')  

    // this doesnt
    if( have_rows('about_team','option') ) {
        while ( have_rows('about_team','option') ) { the_row();
            $person_image = get_sub_field('person_image');
            $person_full_name = get_sub_field('person_full_name');
            break;
        }
    }
    switch_to_blog( $original_blog_id );
}
```

As noted in the commenting the normal fields work, but the moment I try to retrieve data from the repeater field it just comes up empty.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need ACF sync plugin for multisite environment.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/acf-multisite-sync/

if it doesn't help check :
https://github.com/tmconnect/acf-relationship-multisite

another way to do it is :

```
switch_to_blog( $current_site );
$GLOBALS['_wp_switched_stack'] = array();
$GLOBALS['switched']           = FALSE;
```

Comment: Multisite Sync is for easily replicating fields across the network. I do this with the php export code. My fields show up everywhere it should and pulls to the front except for the repeater field.

Comment: Relationship multisite allows me to pull posts, post types, pages from other sites in the network. Not relevant, but I already do this using the switch_to_blog() function programmatically.

Comment: After every instance of switch_to_blog() you need to call restore_current_blog() otherwise WP will think it is in a "switched" mode and can potentially return incorrect data.

Comment: foreach( $blog_ids as $blog_id ){
    switch_to_blog( $blog_id );
    //Do stuff
    restore_current_blog();
 }

Comment: Can you edit your question and paste the code you crafted with the restore_current_blog() function?

Comment: you realize that restore_current_blog() doesn't restore the main blog, but just the previous blog. I updated my code to what I did do.

Comment: I posted it as an issue to Elliot on github, seems to be a bug. Will reply if it's something I'm doing wrong